# using awk how to make csv

Tags: csv, awk

I have output from script which gives me number of exceptions in particular hour. I want make to make a `.csv` file from data. and I think to use `awk` or something else to do it.

```
 44 17-04-15 21
 23 17-04-15 22
 15 17-04-15 23
  9 18-04-15 00
  8 18-04-15 01
  8 18-04-15 02
  9 18-04-15 03
 12 18-04-15 04
 11 18-04-15 05
  1 18-04-15 06
  2 18-04-15 09
  7 18-04-15 10
  7 18-04-15 11
 10 18-04-15 12
```

I expect to get the following result

```
17-04-15,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,44,23,15
18-04-15,9,8,8,9,12,11,1,,,2,7,7,10
```

Comment: Can you post the awk script you have tried using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk        
$2!=prev { prtFlds(); flds[1]=$2 }
{ numFlds=$3+2; flds[numFlds]=$1 }
{ prev=$2 }
END { prtFlds() }
function prtFlds(       fldNr) {
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", flds[fldNr], (fldNr<numFlds?",":ORS)
    }
    delete flds
    numFlds = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
17-04-15,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,44,23,15
18-04-15,9,8,8,9,12,11,1,,,2,7,7,10
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{a[$2,($3+0)]=$1;b[$2];max[$2]=max[$2]<$3?$3:max[$2]} END {for (i in b) {printf i;for (j=0;j<=max[i];j++) printf ",%s",a[i,j];print ""}}' file
17-04-15,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,44,23,15
18-04-15,9,8,8,9,12,11,1,,,2,7,7,10
```

Comment: that will print the dates in a random order instead of the order they appear in the input file which may or may not be ok but it's worth mentioning since you can't tell that from this specific random order of output since it, by coincidence, just happens to be the same as the input order. Also, don't use `a[x FS y]`, just `a[x,y]` is all you need.